# sistema de votação

Tags: php, css

Estou fazendo um site e gostaria que tivesse um sistema de votação, porém eu não queria que fosse com estrelas e sim com xicaras de café (peguei por esse site: font-awesome). Mas não consigo deixar com as xicaras, fica sempre como estrela.

index.php

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
   <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb2dfeaa2c.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Avalie</h1>
   <?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
      echo $_SESSION['msg']."<br><br>";
      unset($_SESSION['msg']);
   }
   ?>
   <form method="POST" action="processa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="estrelas">
         <input type="radio" id="vazio" name="estrela" value="" checked>

         <label for="estrela_um" ><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>

         <input type="radio" id="estrela_um" name="estrela" value="1">

         <label for="estrela_dois" ><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
         <input type="radio" id="estrela_dois" name="estrela" value="2">

         <label for="estrela_tres"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
         <input type="radio" id="estrela_tres" name="estrela" value="3">

         <label for="estrela_quatro"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
         <input type="radio" id="estrela_quatro" name="estrela" value="4">

         <label for="estrela_cinco"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
         <input type="radio" id="estrela_cinco" name="estrela" value="5"><br><br>

         <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar"> <label for="estrela_um" ><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

estilo.css

```
.estrelas input[type=radio]{
display: none;
}.estrelas label i.fa:before{
content: '\f005';
color: #FC0;
}.estrelas  input[type=radio]:checked  ~ label i.fa:before{
color: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere o código da estrela `\f005` pelo da xícara de café `\f0f4`:

```css
.estrelas input[type=radio]{
display: none;
}.estrelas label i.fa:before{
content: '\f0f4';
color: #FC0;
}.estrelas  input[type=radio]:checked  ~ label i.fa:before{
color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb2dfeaa2c.js"></script>
<h1>Avalie</h1>
<form method="POST" action="processa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="estrelas">
      <input type="radio" id="vazio" name="estrela" value="" checked>

      <label for="estrela_um" ><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      
      <input type="radio" id="estrela_um" name="estrela" value="1">
      
      <label for="estrela_dois" ><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input type="radio" id="estrela_dois" name="estrela" value="2">
      
      <label for="estrela_tres"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input type="radio" id="estrela_tres" name="estrela" value="3">
      
      <label for="estrela_quatro"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input type="radio" id="estrela_quatro" name="estrela" value="4">
      
      <label for="estrela_cinco"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input type="radio" id="estrela_cinco" name="estrela" value="5"><br><br>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar"> <label for="estrela_um" ><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Que estranhoo, no meu computador modificou para a xícara, porém não muda de cor como aparece quando executo o codigo que vocÊ me mandou... (quando coloco para executar seu codigo no proprio stackoverflow funciona certinho)

Comment: @fer Veja as versões das bibliotecas da minha resposta e compare com as que vc usa.

Comment: consegui arrumar. Obrigadaaa

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do arquivo **.css**, substitua o caractere de estrela **\f005** pelo da xícara de café **\f0f4**:

```css
.estrelas input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.estrelas label i.fa:before {
  content: '\f0f4';
  color: #FC0;
}

.estrelas input[type=radio]:checked ~ label i.fa:before {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb2dfeaa2c.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Avalie</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="processa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="estrelas">
  <input type="radio" id="vazio" name="estrela" value="" checked>

  <label for="estrela_um"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>

  <input type="radio" id="estrela_um" name="estrela" value="1">

  <label for="estrela_dois"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="estrela_dois" name="estrela" value="2">

  <label for="estrela_tres"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="estrela_tres" name="estrela" value="3">

  <label for="estrela_quatro"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="estrela_quatro" name="estrela" value="4">

  <label for="estrela_cinco"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="estrela_cinco" name="estrela" value="5">
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">

</div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois você está chamando no seu CSS um *"content"* equivalente ao ícone de café.

Você tem duas alternativas.
1) Substituir:

> content: '\f005';

Pelo content do ícone correto:

> content: '\f0f4';

Ou

2) Retirar o *"content"* do seu código, tendo em vista que ele já é chamado na classe do Font Awesome.

Fonte do ícone: http://fontawesome.io/icon/coffee/